# Honor of a lion

Tags: spells, l5r-4e

Some spells look at the honor of the target to determine effect. For example, Water 2 has a healing spell called Heaven's Tears<sup>Book of Water p.181</sup> that only heals Honor 4.0 and up, while harming any tainted person.

Now, what the spell does to a Matsu Beastmaster<sup>Great Clans p.136</sup> is known: his honor rank rules that. But what about his trusty lion companion? Does he get his own honor rank or uses the one of his master or none at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The spell can only affect an animal with Shadowlands Taint

While I have yet to see explicit RAW, on the subject, here are the key factors that I used to come to the conclusion:

- There is no presence of an Honor score on the base lion creature (PHB323)
- Creatures who possess Taint will specifically list the level (PHB318)
- There is a "level zero" for Honor, and Honor by definition requires sentience to have introspection on virtue and make decisions based on etiquette and expectation (PHB90)
- There is a "level zero" for Taint (PHB 277)

Thus, the only thing the lions can do is gain Shadowlands Taint, but when it comes to that and Honor, their starting values are *null* rather than 0